# How do I layer widgets in Tkinter (make shapes in front of image)?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, widget, tkinter-canvas

I'm trying to draw shapes in front of an image, but I don't see them - they're behind it. How do i make the image go back a layer/the shapes go forward a layer? Here is my code:

```py
photo = PhotoImage(file='Alveoli.ppm')
        img = Label(tk, image=photo)
        img.image = photo 
        img.place(x=0, y=0)
        oc = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 400, 400, fill = 'red')
```

@Philipp After using `tag_raise` it still looks like this (the img is on the left):
[image]

Comment: Please accept an answer. If none work, make sure to not use a layout manager like `.pack()`

Answer (score 5):

just use `widget.tkraise(aboveThis=ob)`

if you want the widget to come above all other widgets then use
`widget.tkraise()`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use this method: `tag_raise()`

Which in your case would should look like this:

`canvas.tag_raise(oc)`

Comment: It was still behind the image. I use Python 3.7, just in case `tag_raise()` is a 2.x thing.

Comment: Also, when I use `tag_raise`, do I use `photo` or `img`?

Comment: [Here's](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_lower-method) a link to the documentation.You want to either raise the oval or lower the img. So if you used tag_raise on the img, then nothing happend, because its already on top.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `tag_lower`.

Comment: Are you sure your image and oval are both on the same canvas?

Comment: Can there be multiple canvases? I'm pretty sure. I only made one canvas.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot overlay canvas items on top of embedded widgets. If you want to draw on top of an image, the image must be a canvas object created with `create_image`.

Once you've done that, you can use the canvas methods `lift` and `lower` to change the stacking order (z-index) of an item.

```
photo = PhotoImage(file='Alveoli.ppm')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor="nw")
oc = canvas.create_oval(0, 0, 400, 400, fill = 'red')
```